# Dynamically change within shader

Tags: c++, directx, hlsl

I have a quick question about what the more correct approach to something is.

I'm using C++ DirectX11 for the following example.

Example: 
If you press a key it'll enable textures, if you press another key it'll disable textures.

Approach #1:
Initially the way I was going to do this was to add a bool variable to a cbuffer and then just pass the result of a bool to that variable to determine if the shader renders textures or not.

Approach #2:
As I was reading through the book I bought on DirectX I noticed that he has a separate technique for each object and then for each technique he's setting a bunch of variables that are being passed into the pixel shader. I tried to do this with the example above so that I had two techniques, one with textures and one without textures and then based on the key input to just change the technique name.

Initially the second approach seemed strange to me, even for the variables he's setting for each object I would've imagined it would be better to pass variables to cbuffer variables and then just enclose certain areas with if statements. This led me to think that the first approach to creating flags in shaders to dynamically change them might be a bad way of dealing with things that is beyond my current understanding, so I was curious if anyone could clean this up for me and explain if it matters what you do.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic branching, even if all threads take the same branch, has a non-zero cost every time the shader is run.  Creating different shaders, on the other hand, is a fixed cost at startup.  I'd recommend against effects / techniques, however, as these are deprecated in the latest version of the compiler.  Instead, you should create separate shaders directly.